# How to achieve more semantic urls in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am just learning CI.  I am trying to build my own CMS.  I have successfully created a url structure `www.mydomain.com/pages/getpage/2`, where 2 is the id of the page.

However, I want to remove the '/pages/getpage/2' from the url.  Instead, I want the domain to read `www.mydomain.com/about`, about being the title of the page, which is a column in the db.

I realise this is something to do with routing and maybe htaccess file.

I'm not sure what to put in routing to make the url as I want it.

Comment: can you rephrase your question please?
you want to call `getpage()`  but not from URL? if so from the same controller you can call it by `$this->getpage();` if you want to call it from different controllers, it's best to make a helper that can be accessed universally.

Comment: sorry, I know its difficult to explain.  I'll rewrite.

Comment: I suggest to search for CodeIgniter Dynamic Routes. ([1](http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/06/dynamic-routing-from-database-in-codeigniter/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282346/codeigniter-dynamic-routes)) Here's one strategy, redirect all pages to the default controller `Pages`. In the `index()` method, query your database to check for the page named `About`, if found call `getpage(2)`.  If not found, redirect to 404. Obviously, replace "About" or "2" by variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want www.mydomain.com/pages/getpage/2 to route to www.mydomain.com/about, insert this line in to your routes.php

```
$route['about/(:num)'] = "pages/getpage/$1";
```

your URL structure will be www.mydomain.com/about/2, since you need that id as a reference to your content.

visit [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) for more details on routing

Comment: is it not possible to dynamically create the routes, other than manually typing one in for every page?

Comment: no need to create one for every page. the (:num) wild card will automatically pass your page id to the getpage method in the pages controller

Comment: No I mean for the page name, i.e. rather than typing in 'about', somehow querying the database and getting all page names so dynamically creating these routes?

Comment: I see no feasible way of doing this but I might be wrong. It would be best to change your method to suit the vanity url

Comment: hmm, what way do you suggest doing it?

Comment: lets enter the stackoverflow chat room as not to fill up the original question with comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27197/discussion-between-mehrdad-dastgir-and-nicola)